# ExtJS 4 - how to use Ext.ux.PreviewPlugin

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Since now I have only used plugin for editing and the way I use it is first adding:

```
this.editing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing');
```

in my `initComponent: function` and then apply this:

```
plugins: [this.editing],
```

And I was ready to go. But obv. this approach doesn't work on `Ext.ux.PreviewPlugin` so I googled i little bit and find some kind of example which is:

```
//  requires: 'Ext.ux.PreviewPlugin',


//    disableSelection: true,



    viewConfig: {
        id: 'id',
        trackOver: false,
        stripeRows: false,
        plugins: [{
            ptype: 'preview',
            bodyField: 'excerpt',
            expanded: true,
            pluginId: 'preview'
        }]
    },

    // pluggable renders
    renderTopic: function(value, p, record) {
        return Ext.String.format(
            '<strong><a href="http://sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?t={2}" target="_blank">{0}</a></strong><a href="http://sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f={3}" target="_blank">{1} Forum</a>',
            value,
            record.data.forumtitle,
            record.getId(),
            record.data.forumid
        );
    },
```

but it also doesn't work, at least for me, I get the following error :

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://myLocalSite/index.php/ux/PreviewPlugin.js?_dc=1339593100494"
```

I'm not quite sure which cause this error, also I'm using the example directly so I expected to get some errors because of that, but I think I miss the general approach to using these kinds of plugins, so I think I need some more general points on how to configure this plugin, and maybe then will be able to adjust it for my exact needs.

So either way, a help is needed to get this plugin working.

Thanks

Leron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your ExtJs version but if you're using 4.0.7 - preview plugin wound be by default not in `src\` directory but in `\examples\ux`.

I would recommend to copy it from there to `\src\ux` and make sure you include all dependencies (like special css classes or other stuff from `\examples\ux`)

Comment: The version is 4.1.0. Do you know a good example where this plugin is used? And thanks for the help....again :) I wasn't able to find nothing worthy in internet, it seems as if this plugin is rarely used...

Comment: They actually use preview plugin here I think: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/feed-viewer/feed-viewer.html - see Summary button. But preview will turn on/off for all records at the same time.

Comment: 4.1 has this plugin in the same place - \examples\ux

Comment: Thanks, gonna see the example and then get out of work. Have a nice day and thanks for help. I'll accept your answer but feel like I'll have more to ask about this plugin tomorrow, hope to see you around ;)

Answer (score 0):

For more clear usage an implementation of Ext.ux.PreviewPlugin take a look at official example at ExtJS package folder : examples/feed-viewer/feed-viewer.html. Or online at [[http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/feed-viewer/feed-viewer.html][1]](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/feed-viewer/feed-viewer.html%5d%5b1%5d)

When you see the source code, you can see at around line 36th :

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '../ux');
```

First argument 'Ext.ux' i guest it is the difinition of application path you must put at the required module later by Ext.require() function, and i am sure '../ux' is the relative path of 'ux' directory which contain some official plugins. You can get it from 'example' directory comes with ExtJS package located at : examples/ux . You have to copy those directory somewhere relative to your source code, i would suggest to copy it inside your source code directory.

Then include the plugin at the Ext.require as follow (see feed-viewer.html code around line 48th) :

```
Ext.require([
'Ext.ux.PreviewPlugin'
]);
```